# How to fix "Object of class WP_Term could not be converted to string"?

Tags: php

I basically want to loop through each post I have and get the taxonomy/category id. After that I want to output those id's into a single string (not as a numeric value), separated by a space.

I get this error when I try to echo the string: **"Object of class WP_Term could not be converted to string"**

Here is what i have so far:

```
  <?php
          $taxonomy = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'categories');
          $ids = "";
           
          foreach ($taxonomy as $cat) {
              $ids .= $cat;
        ?>
```

Comment: Note that the taxonomy term is `category`, not `category`. If you use a taxonomy name that doesn't exist `$taxonomy` will be a `WP_Error` object, not an array.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs for the Term object](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/) the ID is in the property `term_id` So you need:

```
    $ids = array();

    foreach ($taxonomy as $tax) {
        $ids[] = $tax->term_id;
    }

    $joinedIds = implode(" ", $ids);

    // do something with $joinedIds;
```

Answer (score 0):

`$cat` is an object, not a string. You are also missing a closing bracket.

Try:  `$ids .= $cat->id . ' ';`

It is often helpful to take a look at the returned structure and data:

```
foreach ($taxonomy as $cat) {
   
    echo '<pre>'; var_dump( $cat ); echo '</pre>';

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I still get nothing when I echo $ids